# Gomoku AI: How to find out if a connect is blocked using bit boards?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm implementing a Gomoku AI with array bit boards. I have 8 arrays board(rows, columns, diagonal /, diagonal \) 4 for human and 4 for computer. Each array holds integers, each of which represents either a row, a column, or a diagonal and upon which I could perform bitwise operations on.

```
public int[] humanRows = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Whenever the human player or computer chooses a move, all four boards belonging to that player get updated. This way, I can check 5-in-a-row easily, which is great.

```
for(int row: humanDiagonals){
        if ((row & (row>>1) & (row>>2) & (row>>3) & (row>>4)) != 0){
            return humanPiece;
        }
    }
```

But now comes the problem. I want to be able to find all patterns (open-4, 4-one-end-blocked, etc) to feed into my evaluation function. But I cant check whether a connect-4 is already blocked because I can't represent all 3 states of a square (empty, X-filled, O-filled) using bit board. If I use & operator to merge bit board, all the filled squares will just be represented as 1 and I won't be able to differentiate them.
I have a method like below, but as you see, it doesn't take into account blocked ends.

```
 public int comboCount(String combo, int[] board) {
    int count = 0;
    int len = combo.length();
    for (int row : board) {
        if (row != 0) { // if the row is not empty
            int shiftedRow = row;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                int temp = row >> i;
                shiftedRow &= temp;
            }
            String rowString = Integer.toBinaryString(shiftedRow);
            for (int k = 0; k < rowString.length(); k++) {
                if (rowString.charAt(k) == '1') {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Can anyone help me find a solution. I have a feeling that the problem has a simple solution, yet I couldn't wrap my head around it. This is my first time tinkering with bits so if possible, please make the solution simple.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check for four-in-a-row (but not longer) for one side first, and then check the merged board for longer rows.

Using these convenience functions...

```
private static boolean hasFourInRow(int row){
    return (row & (row >> 1) & (row >> 2) & (row >> 3)) != 0;
}

private static boolean hasFiveInRow(int row){
    return (row & (row >> 1) & (row >> 2) & (row >> 3) & (row >> 4)) != 0;
}

private static boolean hasSixInRow(int row){
    return (row & (row >> 1) & (row >> 2) & (row >> 3) & 
            (row >> 4) & (row >> 5)) != 0;
}
```

This is how you can easily detect the cases you mentioned:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int humanRow = 0b00011110;
    int computerRow = 0b00100001;

    if (hasFourInRow(humanRow) && !hasFiveInRow(humanRow)){
        int combinedRow = humanRow | computerRow;

        if (!hasFiveInRow(combinedRow)){
            System.out.println("Open 4!");
        } else if (!hasSixInRow(combinedRow)){
            System.out.println("4-one-end-blocked!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("4-both-ends-blocked!");
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't really answer my problem. I'm looking for the total count of let's say all 4-one-end-blocked for human in a board. Your solution works fine if each row only one such pattern appears, but it doesn't work on cases such as this OXXXX-OOOOXXXXO-, where the plethora of pieces make it hard to count the merge board without adding a few already counted pattern.

Comment: I see what you're saying. What would be the expected output for a row like that, then?

Comment: For the case above I would want to get an output of 4-one-end-blocked, 0 4-in-a-row and 1 4-both-end-blocked